# How to launch a postgres docker container with valid initial setting?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Set a postgres docker config file as

Dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:12-alpine

USER postgres

RUN chmod 0700 /var/lib/postgresql/data &&\
    initdb /var/lib/postgresql/data &&\
    echo "host all  all    0.0.0.0/0  md5" >> /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf &&\
    echo "listen_addresses='*'" >> /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
    pg_ctl start &&\
    psql -c "ALTER USER postgres WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'mypassword';"

EXPOSE 5432
```

Deployed it on a server with docker-compose

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  postgresql:
    build:
      context: ./postgresql
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: postgresql
    container_name: postgresql
    hostname: postgresql
```

When build it, it can successful finished. But when up it, got

```
docker-compose up postgresql
Creating postgresql ... done
Attaching to postgresql
postgresql       | Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.
postgresql       |        You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD to a non-empty value for the
postgresql       |        superuser. For example, "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" on "docker run".
postgresql       |
postgresql       |        You may also use "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust" to allow all
postgresql       |        connections without a password. This is *not* recommended.
postgresql       |
postgresql       |        See PostgreSQL documentation about "trust":
postgresql       |        https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html
postgresql exited with code 1
```

Check `docker container ls -a`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
1lsls201qs0h        postgresql          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago       Exited (1) 2 minutes ago                       postgresql
```

The file permission on the server

```
ls -la postgresql/
Total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 runuser runuser  24  April 14 01:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 runuser runuser  54  April 14 01:02 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 runuser runuser 541  April 14 01:02 Dockerfile

ls -la docker-compose.yaml
-rwxr-xr-x 1 runuser runuser 1110  April 14 01:02 docker-compose.yaml
```

I tested it on local, it works. The container can run correctly and the initial password setting also works. But on the server, is there any permission should be changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to create image by modifiying postgress dockerfile.Just download the image and run the image. write your own separate `pg_hba.conf` and `postgresql.conf` and saved it to a host directory.
Now mount that directory at container runtime.check the volume and add this to docker compose.

```
volume:
- host_directory_that_contains_conf/pg_hba.conf: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
- host_directory_that_contains_conf/postgresql.conf: /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
```

Add this volume in your docker-compose and run the docker compose up.
There is a another alternative solutions which is using env variable.
You can add all of this in ENVIRONMENT variable.

Comment: do you have example how to allow remote connections with environment variables?